# Deep Learning: Using a pretrained network's earlier activations

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning, keras

I have around 25k images belonging to 14 different classes (different kinds of neck-lines, e.g.  v-neck, round neck, etc). The images mainly contain the the top-part of the apparel and/or the face of the model. Here are some examples:

[image][image]

In order to do this, I thought of extracting the features after the 1st block of VGG16 (pretrained on imagenet) because the feature map of the earlier blocks will be capturing things lines, shapes, etc. Here is the `model.summary()`:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 802816)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              3288338432
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              16781312  
_________________________________________________________________
predictions (Dense)          (None, 16)                65552     
=================================================================
Total params: 3,305,224,016
Trainable params: 3,305,224,016
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The problem is that the total number of parameters is huge. Can you please advise, considering my specific dataset, how to reduce that?

Comment: Is the loss exactly where it was in the first epoch after 30 epochs? In that case, training on a simple cnn might show if there's any other problems with respect to batches etc.

Comment: @Littleone, please look at the edited questions

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: a dense layer will create weights for each of the inputs.

So, because you've got an image full of pixels, and you haven't reduced its size significantly, adding `Flatten` + `Dense` will result in this absurd amount of weights.

I'm not sure I understand why you want only the first block. This is the block that will be identifying very rudimentar little shapes without considering their relations with each other. And certainly, there are **not any earlier blocks**.

I do recommend that you use more blocks to identify elaborated features and to reduce the image size. The best to do is simply take the entire VGG16 model with `include_top=False` and `trainable=False`, and add your trainable top layers - ([See Here](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16))

Now, if you really really want to have so few blocks and not reduce the image size, then you can try adding a `GlobalMaxPooling2D` layer. This will get only the max values in the entire image. This might or not be useful, depending on how possible it is to identify what you want with so few convolutions. (Another option is `GlobalAveragePooling2D`, but I believe this is even less effective in this case). In this case, more blocks will lead to better results.

Comment: since neckline shapes are not complicated, I thought of using block1 only. My understanding is that the information needed to distinguish between necklines would be captured in the earlier activations and so the later activations are not really needed. Is that not the correct understanding?

Comment: I don't think so. (But in any case, you need to get rid of that huge number of parameters). Rudimentary shapes are color transitions, from white to black, from black to white, vertical, horizontal, diagonal, etc. Not even close to lines yet.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I tried your approach. My dataset contains around 600 images per class (11 classes). After 10 epochs, the training accuracy was 94% but val accuracy was only 72%. Dropouts after the dense layer also did not help. Do you think, I would need some kind of segmentation to provide only the neck region as input?

Comment: You need more data, or data augmentation. Or a less powerful model. You've got an overfitting model (the model is too powerful and it's capable of memorizing your training data).

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your own feature extractor that comes by removing all the dense layers from the original VGG to build your own dense layers. I suggest you to put 2 dense layers also, fc1 with 1024 nodes and fc2 with 512 nodes. Of course you have to add a third dense layer that will be the fake classifier to train the feature extractor. Then train only this three layers keeping the rest of the VGG as `trainable=false`, that will reduce the parameters. For sure after training these layers you should remove the last one to have your feature extractor. Now for every image you would have 512 features that you can fit on a simple NN or a SVM as your choice that would be your classifier. 
You should have a GPU with at least 8gb.

In Keras blog you can find how to finetune your last layers in order to have your own feature extractor that is more or less what are you looking for: https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but you've been confused (as I once was) by an inconsistency in the way people describe neural nets. In Keras docs, the "top" layer is what other docs call the "bottom", "last", "final", or "deepest" layer. It's the layer that calculates the final probabilities. To implement transfer learning, you freeze the early layers (where images enter the network and are convolved) and replace or re-train the final layer (where the answer comes out). Keras calls that final layer "top". So in Keras-talk, you either instantiate the model with include_top=False, or you remove a layer with model.pop().

I hope that helps.

The response from Eric is correct. I second his recommendation that you read this blog post by  François Chollet, the creator of Keras: https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a pre-trained model, you don't have to re-train the lower layers and just keep the last few classification layers to be trainable. For example, if you'd like to freeze the first 6 layers you can call:

```
for idx, layer in enumerate(model.layers[:6]):
    print('Make layer {} {} untrainable.'.format(idx, layer.name))
    layer.trainable = False
```

Then if you call the `model.summary()`, you'll see that you have much less trainable parameters which will not only make the training faster but usually provides better results when you do not alter the pre-trained convolutional layers.