# loss is nan after 1st epoch on cluster but decreasing on laptop

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

When I train on my laptop, even though it crashes after 3 epochs, the loss seems to be decreasing normally. However when I move to cluster with 48 cores, the loss is nan for every epoch after the first epoch. For the first epoch the loss is normal value, i.e 40.9451

Here is my model

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(241, 480, 7)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at your `model.summary()`? It seems your model has more than 100 million weights, which is certainly a bad idea. You may be getting memory or overflow problems. --- Your question is closely related to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48596910/deep-learning-using-a-pretrained-networks-earlier-activations

Comment: Could you provide your `model.compile` instruction?

Comment: `model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')`